# Changing the orientation of Android Keyboard using jQuery or CSS

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, web

I have written a code to lock the orientation of the screen so my app will be fixed in portrait mode alone. Now the Android or iOS keyboard is in landscape mode (including the navigation bar). Now can we change the entire screen to be fixed in Portrait mode include the native elements like keyboard and navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible to do in a web app. There is a draft for it here http://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation/, currently only supported on Firefox OS and Firefox for Android https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.lockOrientation